# how to multiply canvas id (HTML) using several javascript codes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create different canvases in the same HTML code.
Each Js code generates an IP, and I would like to use in the same HTML several Js codes.

If it can help I will post my codes:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("test-canvas");
canvas.addEventListener('wheel', evt => evt.preventDefault());
let engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
let scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
let camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera('cam', Math.PI/2,0.7,15, new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,0), scene);
camera.attachControl(canvas,true);
camera.wheelPrecision = 5;
camera.lowerRadiusLimit = 2;
camera.upperRadiusLimit = 80;            
let light1 = new BABYLON.PointLight('light1',new BABYLON.Vector3(0,1,0), scene);
light1.parent = camera;

const sphereRadius = 0.125;//raggio delle palline
const cylinderRadius = 0.025;//raggio dei cilindri
const cylinderHeight = 3.5;//metti a 10 è bello, comunque, lunghezza dei cilindri
const R = 1.9;//localizzazione oggetto nello spazio

scene.clearColor = BABYLON.Color3.Black();//sfondo nero

let material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial('mat', scene);
material.diffuseColor.set(1,1,1);
let pendulums = [];
const m = 100;
for (let b = 0; b < m; b++) { //b è la parallela di i, indica una lettera per verificare la funzione

    let pendulum = new BABYLON.Mesh('p', scene);//creo l'oggetto pendulum, cioè associazione di sfera e cilindro
    pendulum.r = 6; //raggio oggetto 
    let phi = 2 * Math.PI * b / m; //quanti ne devono essere creati, si può intervenire solo su m nelle costanti, b corrisponde a i , cioè verifica la funzione

    let cyl = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateCylinder('cyl', {//creo i cilindri
        diameter: cylinderRadius * 2,//indico il diametro (si utilizzano le costanti di prima per velocizzare il tutto ma alla fine sono numeri)
        height: cylinderHeight / 2//indico la lunghezza
    }, scene);//posiziono l'oggetto nella scena
    cyl.position.y = -cylinderHeight / 4; //non si può notare cosa accade perchè non è presente una griglia, comunque corrisponde alla posizione verticale dei cilindri rispetto all'oggetto parent
    cyl.parent = pendulum;//associo l'oggetto cilindro al pendolo

    let spheres = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateSphere("s",//creo le sfere
        { diameter: sphereRadius * 2 },//indico il diametro 
        scene);//posiziono l'oggetto
    spheres.position.y = -cylinderHeight / 2;//anche in questo caso indico la posizione delle sfere in relazione all'oggetto parent
    spheres.parent = pendulum;//associo l'oggetto sfera al cilindro
    spheres.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("m", scene);//creo il materiale per modificare il colore delle sfere
    spheres.material.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(//creo i colori e i parametri che si devono rispettare (limite azzurrino-viola-blu)
    0.5 + 0.9 * Math.cos(phi),
    0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sin(phi),
    0.5 + 0.1 * Math.sin(2 * phi),
    );

    pendulum.position.set(//posiziono i pendoli rispetto al centro e quindi rispetto alla circonferenza del sistema di pianeti
        R * Math.cos(phi),//posizone lungo x, troviamo raggio e la posizione dell'oggetto parallelamente al geometra 
        1,
        -R * Math.sin(phi) 
    );
    pendulums.push(pendulum);//butto fuori gli oggetti pendolo
}

engine.runRenderLoop(function() { 
    let t = performance.now() * 0.001;
    
    pendulums.forEach((pendulum,il) => {
      pendulum.rotation.x = t - pendulum.position.length()*0.3;
      let phe = Math.PI * 4 * il/ m;
      pendulum.rotation.y = phe;//associo l'angolo alla rotazione lungo y
      pendulum.rotation.z = phe / 2 + t * 3;// indico quanto vale il tempo
      //pendulum.position.set(5* Math.cos(t),0,5* Math.sin(t));
      //pendulum.scaling.set(Math.cos(t),2*Math.cos(t),Math.sin(t));//only without position
    });

    scene.render();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.babylonjs.com/babylon.js"></script>
        <style>
            body { padding:20px;}
            canvas {
                border: 3px solid orange;
                box-shadow: 15px 15px 40px purple;
            }
            .signature {
              text-align: right;
              font-size:smaller;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Metodi matematici per l'animazione</h1>
        <canvas id="test-canvas" width="500" height="420"></canvas>
        <h2>Esempio</h2>
        <canvas id="test-canvas1" width="700" height="420"></canvas>
        <!--  ====================== CODICE ==============================================================  -->
        <script src="example.js"></script>
        <script src="example1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the second js code is really similar but with, of course, a different IP in the first line

as you can see it doesn't appear to me anything in the second window. I tried to switch the elements and what I "found" is that it shows the first IP it receives.

Thank you so much

Comment: To reuse it, simply wrap it in [a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), then pass the element and/or options `ip(document.getElementById("test-canvas1"))`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).